# Average of Arrays

Tags: java

My code is supposed to calculate the average of the array values and print it.
Here I have,

```
public class ArrayAverageTester
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] numArray =  {12, 17, 65, 7, 30, 88};

     // Create an ArrayAverage object and print the result
     ArrayAverage[] arr = {12, 17, 65, 7, 30, 88};

     System.out.println("The average of the array is " + arr.getAverage()); 

   }
}
```

And my ArrayAverage class,

```
public class ArrayAverage
{
   private int[] values;

   public ArrayAverage(int[] theValues)
   {
      values = theValues;
   }

   public double getAverage()
   {
     int sum = 0;  

     for(int value : values)
     {
       sum += value;
     }

   return (sum/values.length);
   }
}
```

My error says that int can't be converted to ArrayAverage and that I have forgotten to declare the method getAverage() or it's out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `getAverage()` method performs integer math (currently). You could fix that like

```
public double getAverage() {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int value : values) {
        sum += value;
    }

    return (sum / (double) values.length);
}
```

Next, you need to *construct* a **new** `ArrayAverage` instance (not an array of them) and pass the constructor your array to average. Like,

```
ArrayAverage arr = new ArrayAverage(numArray);
```

Outputs

```
The average of the array is 36.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct. `ArrayAverage[]` means "array of `ArrayAverage`s". You should either:

- just declare a normal `int[]`
- create a single instance of `ArrayAverage`

The error you get is your compiler looking for the function `getAverage()` defined on an **array**, not `ArrayAverage`.

Both of the following methods should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    double count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        count += values[i];
    }

    count /= values.length;

    System.out.println(count);
}
```

or, using your class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new ArrayAverage(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).getAverage());
}
```

with

```
public class ArrayAverage {
    private int[] values;

    public ArrayAverage(int[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public double getAverage() {

        double count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            count += values[i];
        }
    return /= values.length;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a basic problem about object-oriented programming, to test your ArrayAverage class it is necessary to instantiate an object (for this it use the reserved word “new”), and the mistake is that you are creating an ArrayAverage array.

To make it work as you wish, you only need to send numArray to your ArrayAverage class as a parameter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numArray =  {12, 17, 65, 7, 30, 88};

    // Create an ArrayAverage object and print the result
    ArrayAverage arr = new ArrayAverage(numArray);

    System.out.println("The average of the array is " + arr.getAverage()); 
}
```

Answer

> The average of the array is 36.0